# PDOException “could not find driver” after configuring

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to migrate form using mysql to PDO, the following code is meant to make a connection

```
try{
   $DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);  
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Error: <br>";
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Running the php file will print out

```
Error: 
could not find driver
```

I have tried doing the following in putty

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo pecl install pdo_mysql
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And I have added the following lines in php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

yet I still get the error, what could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **MsSQL** in your code but installing **MySQL** driver, or did I miss somethng?
Install PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php but according to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php the driver is only availible to Windows installation.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that, it seemed a tutorial I was following had a typo

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: PDO_SQLSRVR http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php
you are installing mysql driver and using mssql, correct?

Comment: yes, it was a mistake, it should have been mysql instead of mssql

Comment: Are you still getting the error even after fixing the source?