# how to add sql server extensions in php using wamp

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to add sql server  extensions to php  but it gives error of missing driver

extension=php_sqlsrv.dll;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153869/error-could-not-find-driver-after-installing-php-pdo-mssql-dll-on-wampserv

Comment: Does the DLL exist in the correct folder?

Comment: yes... php/php5.5.12/ext/

Comment: Did you restart the server after un-commenting the line in the php.ini?

Comment: Yes.. I did...a dialog box came up with an error that php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll is win32 compatible. but i am using 64 bit WAMP ... is there any issue with that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the dll first. And this depends on your PHP-Version.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Here you can download the driver.

Before check the exact PHP-Version and download the correct Thread-Safe version for Windows.

**Edit:**
You have to install the MSSQL-Client on your system. Otherwise you can't connect.

Comment: I have installed SQL SERVER 2008... isn't there any solution for it..??